# Get IP address (as string) from struct addrinfo

Tags: c, linux, sockets, network-programming

I have a `struct addrinfo` and this is passed to make a connection:

```
struct addrinfo* address;
...
int fd = socket(address->ai_family, address->ai_socktype, address->ai_protocol);
...
int res = ::connect(fd, address->ai_addr, address->ai_addrlen);
```

I'd like to log the destination IP address if the connection is successful.

How do you extract the IP address (as a string to log) from this struct? Google search results only give results for `getaddrinfo()`.

Comment: But examples with `getaddrinfo` are calling it to populate the `struct addrinfo` you already have. Just skip a step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [[Man7]: INET_NTOP(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/inet_ntop.3.html):

1. Cast *ai_addr* member to *sockaddr_in* (or *sockaddr_in6*) structure
2. Call *inet_ntop* on (above) structure's *sin_addr* (*sin6_addr*) member

*code00.c*:

```c
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>


int main()
{
    struct addrinfo *pai = NULL;
    int err = getaddrinfo("www.example.com", NULL, NULL, &pai);
    if (err != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error in getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(err));
        return -1;
    }
    if (pai->ai_family == AF_INET) {
        struct sockaddr_in *psai = (struct sockaddr_in*)pai->ai_addr;
        char ip[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
        if (inet_ntop(pai->ai_family, &(psai->sin_addr), ip, INET_ADDRSTRLEN) != NULL) {
            printf("IP: %s\n", ip);
        }
    } else if (pai->ai_family == AF_INET6) {
        struct sockaddr_in6 *psai = (struct sockaddr_in6*)pai->ai_addr;
        char ip[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
        if (inet_ntop(pai->ai_family, &(psai->sin6_addr), ip, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN) != NULL) {
            printf("IP: %s\n", ip);
        }
    } else {
        printf("Don't know how to convert family %d addresses\n", pai->ai_family);
    }
    freeaddrinfo(pai);
    printf("\nDone.\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**:

> ```bash
> [cfati@cfati-5510-0:/mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackExchange/StackOverflow/q075843180]> ~/sopr.sh
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [064bit prompt]> gcc -o main00.exe main00.c
> [064bit prompt]> ./main00.exe
> IP: 93.184.216.34
>
> Done.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `inet_ntop` to convert an IPv4 or IPv6 address into a string.

```
char addr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
if (inet_ntop(address->ai_family, address->ai_addr, addr, address->ai_addrlen)) {
    printf("address=%s\n", addr);
} else {
    perror("invalid address");
}
```